# Deploy github Private repo to a Shared Hosting

Tags: github, deployment, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have seen many way of deploying github repo to a share hosting.(Cpanel)
But there are so many, not the same and not clear solution have seen especcially for me.
First is - I want to know that the hosting will change automatically when we updated a deployed repo.
Seond - can we manage that manually and automatically for changes.(Prefer automatically , Just want to know for manually.)
Third - If you can show me the light please be my Sensei...
You can give me a link that is already solved this problem.It's OK for me.
Thank you very much...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are looking for. A good way of deploying your GitHub repository to CPanel is through GitHub Actions and an FTP connection.

Create a new action in your GitHub repository, which will prompt the creation of a `main.yaml` file which you can fill with the following code taken from https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ftp-deploy.

```
on: push
name:  Deploy website on push
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name:  Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.0
      with:
        server: ftp.samkirkland.com
        username: myFtpUserName
        password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
```

Customize your server, username and password (preferably using repository secret variables) and every time there is a commit to the main branch, the files will be uploaded/modified in the FTP repository.

Here is a walkthrough in case you need more help: https://youtu.be/UNWIXYSZfZY